# How can I build a JAR library with dependencies with Gradle?

Tags: maven, gradle, jar, nexus

I have a Java project, and I need to publish it to a [Nexus repository](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus/repository-pro). Now I have two options: build a plain JAR file with *.class* files only or build a fat JAR file. Is there a third option that allows to include the *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* or *[pom.xml](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#What_is_the_POM.3F)* file in my JAR file which would specify required dependencies from that Nexus for my library?

I'm not sure that is how libraries work, but I unzipped some libraries from [Maven Central](https://shibboleth.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/DEV/pages/1123844333/Use+of+Maven+Central). They are not fat JAR files, but they contain *pom.xml* files.

Are libraries ever published to the Maven repository built with Gradle that depends on other libraries?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use the Maven Publishing Plugin in Gradle.

Here's an example of how you can configure your *[build.gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html)* file to publish your library to a Nexus repository with its POM file.

Update to yours:

```html
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = 'com.your group package' // Set your group ID
version = '1.2.0' // Set your version

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            // Set the POM configuration
            pom {
                withXml {
                    // Add dependencies to the POM file
                    def dependenciesNode = asNode().appendNode('dependencies')

                    // Add each dependency to the POM file
                    configurations.compile.getResolvedConfiguration().firstLevelModuleDependencies.each { dependency ->
                        def dependencyNode = dependenciesNode.appendNode('dependency')
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('groupId', dependency.moduleGroup)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('artifactId', dependency.moduleName)
                        dependencyNode.appendNode('version', dependency.moduleVersion)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            // Set your Nexus repository URL
            url 'http://your nexus repository url'

            // you can set the repository credentials if necessary
            credentials {
                username 'your username'
                password 'your password'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then run `./gradlew publish` to publish your library to the Nexus repository.

Comment: where shoud pom.xml file appear? this does not change my jar

Comment: If you're using Gradle to build your project, the build.gradle file is the equivalent configuration file. However, the pom.xml file is commonly used in Maven projects, where it serves as the project's configuration file....the one above is just a sample

Comment: i do know what is build.gradle and pom.xml. my question was how to build my own library with indication on which other libraries it depends. i can create jar file and publish it to nexus, but it would not work in projects without same dependencies. or i can build fat jar, but it should not be published in nexus for obvious reasons

Comment: Ok I get you.. ill update the code now

Comment: try the above.. you can update to your config

Comment: build fails with exception
class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression cannot be cast to class org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression (org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.TupleExpression and org.codehaus.groovy.ast.expr.ArgumentListExpression are in unnamed module of loader org.gradle.internal.classloader.VisitableURLClassLoader @2

Comment: Update Gradle: Ensure that you are using a compatible version of Gradle. Update your gradle-wrapper.properties file to use the latest Gradle version. For example, set distributionUrl to https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-x.x.x-all.zip, where x.x.x represents the desired Gradle version.

run ./gradlew clean
and try again

Comment: Could not apply withXml() to generated POM
Could not get unknown property 'compile' for configuration container of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfigurationContainer.

Comment: switched compile to runtimeClasspath. now the error is Invalid publication 'mavenJava': POM file is invalid. Check any modifications you have made to the POM file.

Comment: ok, i've looked into publishing block. i think thats what i wanted, thanks

Comment: are you good now? if yes then you can mark the answer for others to learn

Comment: the pom block here does not work. delete it, and you will be able to publish your library to repository with pom.xml that contains dependencies. note that in your library you should use plugin java-library and implement dependencies via api, not implementation for them to be transitively accessible